# Understanding Reverse Polish Notation, for homework assignment?

Tags: c, programming-languages

I have been asked to write a simple Reverse Polish Notation calculator in C as part of a homework assignment.  I'm having difficulty understanding RPN. Can you please help me understand Reverse Polish Notation?  Also, any tips on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rebooted comments and reopened the question.  Thanks to those who edited for clarity and content.

Comment: @Daniel: what you wrote in that question has nothing to do with what OP asked. As for RPN there are already enough explanations on this site.

Comment: you RPN understand you program write sequence

Comment: @SilentGhost I was trying to reword his original question in a way that would actually get answers, but that could still help him achieve his goal.  So what if his original question was the classic newbie "PLZ HELP!!!"  Teach by example: here's how to actually ask a question when stuck like this.

Comment: @SilentGhost Also, if this has already been addressed in previous question, then post a link to those questions to help him find them.  You don't have to do his work for him, but you don't need to give him the finger either.

Answer (score 14):

[Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_Notation) is a specific way of writing expressions where first you write the values, then the operation you want to perform. So for instance, to add the numbers 3 and 4 you'd write `3 4 +`.

So to write an RPN calculator you'll need

- A means of accepting input, such as from the console
- A means of [tokenizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenize) the input (for what you're doing, breaking on whitespace is probably sufficient)
- A [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)) for storing values (operands) (such as the 3 and 4 in the above)
- A dictionary of operations

Then the loop becomes, in essence:

```
while (there's a token available) {
    token = get_the_token
    if (token is known operator) {
        get the number of values from stack this operation requires (usually two); fail if stack doesn't have enough
        perform operation on values
        push result on the stack
    }
    else if (token is valid value) {
        push it on the stack
    }
    else {
        show error: invalid input
    }
}
show result remaining on stack
```

You can see why RPN makes writing a calcuator fairly easy: You don't have to worry about having operators between the values they operate on, and you don't need parentheses for grouping as you do with the more common [infix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) form of notation. For instance, where we'd write `(10 + (4 * 2)) / 9` in infix notation, we'd write `10 4 2 * + 9 /` in RPN. Your calculator would process those tokens like this:

- `10`: It's a value, push it on the stack
- `4`: It's a value, push it on the stack
- `2`: It's a value, push it on the stack
- `*`: It's an operator, pop 2 and 4 off the stack and multiply them (`4 * 2`); push the result (8) on the stack
- `+`: It's an operator, pop 8 and 10 off the stack and add them (`10 + 8`); push the result (18) on the stack
- `9`: It's a value, push it on the stack
- `/`: It's an operator, pop 9 and 18 off the stack and divide them (`18 / 9`); push the result (2) on the stack (note that the value at the top of the stack — 9, in this case — is the divisor, the next value under it — 18 — is the dividend)
- End of input, show the value(s) on the stack: `2`

Comment: Nice. What, why and how in a concise package.

Answer (score 4):

[Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) is a form of notation for mathematical expressions where the operators follow the operands.  When evaluating an RPN expression, each binary operator refers to the two operands *immediately preceding it*.  Take this RPN expression for example:

```
5 4 3 + *
```

Start scanning the expression from the left until you come to the first operator, which is `+`.  This operator has the operands `4` and `3` (the ones that come immediately before it), so we can replace all three with the result, `7`.  (Note that the parentheses aren't necessary, but I'm using them to help clarify the meaning).

```
5 (4 3 +) * => 5 7 *
```

Now we have the operator `*`, and the two operands `5` and `7` (which is really the result of 4 + 3).  We multiply `5` and `7` and the whole expression evaluates to `35`.

```
5 7 * => 35
```

This is the general algorithm for evaluating any RPN expression.

---

RPN expressions are particularly well suited for evaulation by computers using a data structure known as a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29).

A stack is an ordered collection, where one end is designated the "top".  Items are always added to the stack or removed from the stack at the top.  This way, the only item to remove is always the item that was added most recently.  For this reason, stacks are sometimes referred to as Last In, First Out (or LIFO), because the last element pushed onto the stack is on the top, and thus will be the first to be removed.

In C, you could implement a stack with two variables: an array (large enough to hold the maximum number of elements you expect the stack to ever need) and an integer which indicates which index in the array is currently the top.

Stacks are well suited for evaluating an RPN expression because when you encounter an operator, it always applies to the most recently encountered operands.  So as you scan the expression from the left, you can save the operands on a stack.  Take our example again:

```
5 4 3 + *
```

The first thing here is an operand (`5`), so push it onto a stack (which is initially empty).  Then we encounter `4` and push it on the stack as well.  It becomes the new top.  Then we do the same with `3`.

```
5 4 3 <-- top
+ * // Remaining expression
```

Next we encounter the `+` operator.  We know it applies to the previously encountered operands, but where do we find them?  On top of the stack, of course!  Pop `3` and `4` from the stack and add them to get `7`.  But what to do with the result?  Well, it could be the operand to another operator, so push it back on the stack (just like we replaced the operands and operator with the result when we evaluated the expression by hand):

```
5 7 <-- top
* // Remaining expression
```

Now we see `*`.  Once again, the most recently encountered operands are the two top operands on the stack.  We pop them and multiply to get `35`, then push it back on the stack.

```
35 <-- top
// No expression remaining
```

At this point, we've reached the end of the expression and the only thing on the stack is the result.  We're done!  You can see how the operand stack "saves" the first operands encountered until the corresponding operator is encountered, which could be on the other end of the expression.

If we'd reached the end and found that there was more than one number left on the stack, that would have told us that there were too many operands in the expression and not enough operators.  On the other hand, if we had encountered an operator at some point and had fewer than two operands on the stack, we would know there were too many operators and not enough operands in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Reverse_Polish_Notation.aspx

Comment: Beware, the code in this example is C++.  You will need to translate it to get it to work in C.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a simple implementation at http://expressionoasis.vedantatree.com/