# Recursive Calculation of a queue

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have a some elements in a queue (for example `/ - 4 2 + 4 5`).

that need to be calculated as `(4-2)/(4+5)`. Can someone explain to me the 
**recursive** algorithm about this?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722889/understanding-reverse-polish-notation-for-homework-assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to understand a [polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) that is a form of notation for logic, arithmetic, and algebra.

The expression for adding the numbers 4 and 5 is, in prefix/polish notation, written `+ 4 5` rather than `4 + 5`.

The expression for subtracting the numbers 4 and 2 is, in prefix/polish notation, written `- 4 2` rather than `4 - 2`.

Then, operations can be composed. `op3 (op1 m1 n1) (op2 m2 n2)`, which can be interpreted as `(m1 op1 n1) op3 (m2 op2 n2)`, where `op1`, `op2`, `op3` can be `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`.

Parentheses are optional and the previous polish notation can be written
`op3 op1 m1 n1 op2 m2 n2`

The easiest way to understand it, is to use a tree. A tree will also help you to better understand the recursive algorithm that are used to evaluate such notations. On such a tree, any operation will be considered as a node, and numbers are leaves.

To evaluate an expression, one needs:

- to parse the expression: it consists in identifying the operators and the numbers and build the associate tree.
- to visit the created tree to evaluate all operations and produce the final result.

Comment: well thats helpfull really ... but how can i implement it in a function which use recursive method to return the result

Comment: Think of the expression `(4-2)/(4+5)` as a tree. `/` is the root of the tree, `-` and `+` are the vertices connected to `/`, `4` and `2` are the vertices connected to `-` and `4` and `5` are the vertices connected to `+`. Then notice that the inner nodes of the tree are operators and the leafs are numbers. You can then calculate the expression by evaluating the tree in a depth first search approach using a recursice function.